# Finding Joint Probability of Dependent Events

Tags: probability, statistics

> Determine all joint probabilities from the following
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb P(A) &= 4/5\\
> \mathbb P(B\mid A) &= 2/5\\
> \mathbb P(A^C)&=1/5\\
> \mathbb P(B\mid A^C)&=7/10.
> \end{align}

I have solved for P(A and B), which was 0.32, as well as P(Ac and B), which was 0.14. As far as I can tell, there are only two answers, but the solution tells me that there are actually 4 possible answers. I cannot figure out what the other joint probabilities are. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The solution I was given: .32, .48, .14, .06

Edit: Thank you for all your answers, I can't believe I missed B complement.

Comment: I think it is also asked for $P(A\cap B^c)=P(B^c|A)\cdot P(A)=(1-P(B|A))\cdot P(A)=\frac35\cdot \frac45=\frac{48}{100}$

Comment: Also $P(A^c\cap B^c)=P(B^c|A^c)\cdot P(A^c)=(1-P(B|A^c))\cdot P(A^c)$

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you computed, $$
\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(A) = 2/5\cdot4/5=8/25,
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(A^C\cap B) = \mathbb P(B\mid A^C)\mathbb P(A^C) = 7/10\cdot1/5= 7/50.
$$
However, it remains to compute $\mathbb P(A\cap B^C)$ and $\mathbb P(A^C\cap B^C)$. For these I would recommend rearranging the terms and using the fact that $\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(A^C)=1$:

$$
\mathbb P(A\cap B^C) = \mathbb P(B^C\cap A) = \left(1-\mathbb P(B^C\mid A)\right)\mathbb P(A) = 3/5\cdot4/5=12/25,
$$

$$
\mathbb P(A^C\cap B^C) = \mathbb P(B^C\cap A^C) = \left(1 - \mathbb P(B^C\mid A^C)\right)\mathbb P(A^C) = 3/10\cdot 1/5 = 3/50.
$$

Comment: @callculus I don't see any errors but feel free to edit and correct them if you do.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I believe the computations were correct nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Rule for Probability of Complements: $$\mathsf P(B^\complement\mid A)=1-\mathsf P(B\mid A)$$ et cetera.